# CSSParseError when adding boostrap to an html file in Django and turn it into a pdf

Tags: python, django, xhtml2pdf

Im trying to make a simple report in my Django app, and download it into a pdf Im using xhtml2pdf to do so, when I build my html the page looks fine on my browser, but when turn in into a pdf Im getting this error

```
Selector Pseudo Function closing ')' not found:: (':not(', '[controls]) {\n  disp')
```

I tried to isolate the issue and noticed everything works fine until I paste the bootstrap css code into my html, Im currenty Bootstrap v3.3.4

This is my render_to_pdf function

```
def render_to_pdf(template_src, context_dict={}):
    """Function to render a django template into a pdf """
    template = get_template(template_src)
    html  = template.render(context_dict)
    result = BytesIO()
    pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(BytesIO(html.encode("ISO-8859-1")), result)
    if not pdf.err:
        return HttpResponse(result.getvalue(), content_type='application/pdf')
    return None
```

and this is were I make the actual pdf

```
def print_pdf(request):

   policy = Policy.objects.get(pk=20)
    context = {
        'policy' : policy
    }
    pdf = render_to_pdf('pdfs/payment-control.html', context)
    return HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
```

I hope you guys can help me